# Why does JLabel not display '/' when it is the first character?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have an swing panel with a JLabel inside of it.  The JLabel looks like this:

```
new JLabel("<html>/Foo <br/>/Bar <br/>/Foo<br/>/Bar</html>");
```

However it displays in the UI like the following:

> Bar
>
> Foo
>
> Bar

For some reason, the first line just disappears.  If I take out the slash or remove the html tags, it works as expected.  Is there a way to make the first line show up with the slash?  The reason this even showed up is that we have JLabels which are populated by third party data.  I could programatically remove the slash, but I would prefer to show it in the UI if there is a way to do it.  We are using html and the BR tags in order to make sure each value is on a separate line.

Comment: Using HTML layout engine just for new lines is an overkill

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess its a parsing problem. It works if you add the body tags:

```
"<html><body>/Foo <br/>/Bar <br/>/Foo<br/>/Bar</body></html>"
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a known bug. You can find it here in the [bug lists](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6789978).