# Java JLabel, Why does "<html>/* test */</html>" result in the JLabel being empty?

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel

I have a `JLabel` I'm populating it like this

```
String descriptionText = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(rule.getDescription());
descriptionText = descriptionText.replaceAll("\n", "<br>");
descriptionLbl.setText(String.format("<html>%s</html>", descriptionText));
```

In this case, if `rule.getDescription()` returns something like `"/* test */"` the end result is an empty `JLabel`? Why is this?  I thought that `StringEscapeUtils#escapeHtml` would have caught all the escape characters.

Comment: Hm.../* test */ is a java comment, but OP is talking about inside of a string, inside of HTML.  So java commenting syntax is irrelevant.

Comment: Have you tried doing `System.out.println(descriptionText);` just before setting the label text to see if that string contains what you expect?  Also try putting the result of the `format` call into a String variable so you can print that out for confirmation also.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits Yup. It is pretty strange.  I'm fine doing a find and replace on /*, but I would like to know if I'm going to run into some other crazyness down the line.  I couldn't find any documentation that would explain why this happens.

Comment: @Cogman just for grins, have you tried <html><pre>/* test */</pre></html>?   I can't give you an answer here, I can just commiserate in that I've had a lot of problems with HTML in swing apps.  I try to avoid it if I can because it has a lot of edge cases and strange details.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits pre works as expected, The only issue I have with it is that it ends up changing the font.

Comment: @stvcisco the values going in and coming out are as expected. I've placed breakpoints around the code to verify what went in.  It looks like an undocumented JLabel quirk.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408160/why-does-jlabel-not-display-when-it-is-the-first-character

Comment: Ya, I tried it with a JLabel and see the same thing.  Very strange. If I add a space after html it displays (like `<html >`) and if there's no comment it also displays. Calling `getText()` on the label also shows the text is actually there.  No clue why it's not rendering in some cases.

Comment: @stvcisco As mentioned in the linked question: This is caused by a bug in JLabel ( http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6688690 )

Comment: @Marco13 thanks - just read it. Funky issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a smaller test app that shows the problem:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class LabelTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel label = new JLabel();

        String text = "<html>/test</html>";

        label.setText(text);

        frame.add(label);

        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The only fix I've found is to use the special html code instead:

```
String text = "<html>&#47;test</html>";
```

You could have a processing method that uses replaceAll() to automate this process.

I'm not sure why this happens, and it doesn't seem to happen with any other special character. Weird.